# Electron Project cannot file with correct path

Tags: electron, filepath

I have the following function that is trying to load a .ejs file with the following path.

```
function PaintNewOpponent() {

ejs.renderFile('views/NewOpponent.ejs', {pPlayer:pPlayerLocal}, function(err, str) {
    $("#AddPlayerDialog").html(str);
    alert(err)

    RenderEvents();
    FillInModalinformation()        
});
```

}

I have run an alert check with __dirname and have discovered that I am in the correct directory. Here is a screenshot of my explorer window from Visual Studio Code.

[image]

the directory html is in my root directory. __dirname returns that I am in */html/js*. PaintNewOpponent() is inside my NewOpponent.js file. Yet the ejs.renderFile call comes back in error saying it cannot file the file. Everything is in place.

If necessary here is package.json file

```
{
  "name": "combattracker",
  "version": "3.0.0",
  "description": "AutoHARP 3: Combat Tracker",
  "main": "index.js",
  "license": "ISC",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "electron .",
    "package-mac": "electron-packager . --overwrite --platform=darwin --arch=x64 --icon=assets/icons/mac/icon.icns --prune=true --out=release-builds",
    "package-win": "electron-packager . electron-tutorial-app --overwrite --asar=true --platform=win32 --arch=ia32 --icon=assets/icons/win/icon.ico --prune=true --out=release-builds --version-string.CompanyName=CE --version-string.FileDescription=CE --version-string.ProductName=\"AutoHARP 3\"",
    "package-linux": "electron-packager . electron-tutorial-app --overwrite --asar=true --platform=linux --arch=x64 --icon=assets/icons/png/icon.png --prune=true --out=release-builds"
  },
  "author": "David Klecker",
  "dependencies": {
    "bootstrap": "^4.5.2",
    "bootstrap-sass": "^3.4.1",
    "commonjs": "0.0.1",
    "ejs": "^3.1.5",
    "electron": "^10.1.2",
    "electron-alert": "^0.1.11",
    "electron-reload": "^1.5.0",
    "embed-js": "^5.0.4",
    "jquery": "^3.5.1",
    "parser": "^0.1.4",
    "popper.js": "^1.16.1",
    "uniter": "^2.16.0",
    "xml2js": "^0.4.23",
    "xmlbuilder": "^15.1.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "electron-packager": "^15.1.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: I have also added js/ to the front of the path thinking that perhaps the directory might be the path of html page where the script is linked. That also did not address the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if this will help but what I do is to  build an absolute path using the [path](https://nodejs.org/api/path.html) library (actually I use [upath](https://www.npmjs.com/package/upath) for cross platform compatibility because I often need to save the path to a file).

```
const iconPath = upath.joinSafe(__dirname, 'app', 'assets', 'win_icon_64x64.png');
```

Comment: Something like this might have to be the fix. I wish I knew why this was happening for this particular project. It wasn't needing an absolute path for a previous project. But I will move forward with just giving it an absolute path for the time until perhaps we figure out why a relative path isn't working. Thank you!